# Max of a linear system

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

A Basic Fruit Basket consists of 2 apples, 1 banana, and 1 pear, and costs 5$.

A Premium Fruit basket has 1 apple, 0 bananas, and 2 pears, and costs 7$. Assuming I need a minimum of 8 apples, 6 bananas, and 8 pears, how many of each basket should I buy to spend the smallest amount of money? Explain.

I have solved this through a system of linear equations and get $P = 7/2$ and we need $\max(10P+ 47)$ and I get an answer of $82. Is this correct? Happy to show steps, but feel something is not right.

My attempt:

2A + 1B + 1 P = 5

1A + 2P = 7

Need:

8A + 6B + 8P

So, A = 7 – 2P

And, 2(7-2P) + B + P = 5

And, 14-4P + P + B = 5

And, 14-3P + B = 5

And, 9 – 3P + B = 0

And, B = 3P – 9

So, 8A + 6(3P – 9) + 8P    8(7-2P) + 18P – 9 + 8P   10P + 47
And, Max(10P + 47) = 10($7/2) + 47 = $82

Since, -4P = -14  P = $7/2

Comment: P is a variable. I got my answer is $82. Is that correct by you? I can show steps, but think I have the method but want to confirm if my answer is correct.

Comment: P is for Pears. I can include my steps but need some help. Thanks

Comment: what strange non-ASCII symbols that my browser can't display  did you use in the last two lines

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to find nonnegative integers $x,y$ is to minimize
$$
5x+7y
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\,
$$
subject to the constraints
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
2x+y&\ge 8&&\bigl(\text{apples}\bigr)\\[4pt]
x&\ge 6&&\bigl(\text{bananas}\bigr)\\[4pt]
x+2y&\ge 8&&\bigl(\text{pears}\bigr)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
where $x$ represents the number of basic baskets purchased, and $y$ represents the number of premium baskets purchased.

Here's an unsophisticated solution . . .

First suppose $y=0$.

With $y=0$, the constraints reduce to $x\ge 8$.

Note that if $x=8$ and $y=0$, the cost is $\$40$, so that's the least possible cost if we choose $y=0$.

Next suppose $y\ge 1$.

We already have the constraint $x\ge 6$, and now, by assumption we also have $y\ge 1$.

Note that if $x=6$ and $y=1$, all the constraints are satisfied, and the cost is $\$37$, hence, since $37 < 40$, it follows that the minimum cost is $\$37$, using $x=6$ and $y=1$.

As an alternative method, here's a graphical approach . . .

In the diagram below

[image]

the points which satisfy all $3$ constraints (the shaded region) are the points which are on or above the both of the lines $2x+y=8$ and $x+2y=8$, and also on or to the right of the line $x=6$.

and the diagram below

[image]

illustrates the fact that the least value of $c$ ("$c$" for "cost") for which the line $5x+7y=c$ intersects the shaded region is the value of $c$ such that the line $5x+7y=c$ passes through the point $(6,1)$, namely $c=37$.